# what is wrong with this python code - SyntaxError?

Tags: python

I keep getting an error whenever I enter this code (I'm a python noob so I'm probably missing something obvious)

```
def expadd(num, exp):
    while ((num and exp) != (1001)):
        return (num ^ exp) + expadd((num + 1), (exp + 1))
    return 0
buffer = str(expadd(1000, 1000)
total = 0 #error here "syntax error"
for i in range(1,10):
    total = total +  int(buffer[-i])
print total
```

Comment: Indentation is important in python. Make sure your what you posted matches your code exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the syntax error, there is also a logical error:

```
while ((num and exp) != (1001)):
```

will always be `True`, because both `0` and `1` are different from `1001`. `(num and exp)` checks if both `num` and `exp` are `True`ish (which, for numbers, is the case if they are not `0`). The result of this will either be `1` (`True`) or `0` (`False`), and both of them are different from `1001`.

Then, @interjay noted correctly that you should be using `if`, not `while`.

You probably meant

```
if (num != 1001) and (exp != 1001):
```

(the parentheses are not necessary, I just added them for clarity)

Also, `^` is binary `xor`, not exponentiation. That is the `**` operator:

```
>>> 2^4
6
>>> 2**4
16
```

Comment: Doing `while ___: return ___` is questionable as well, as it is the same effect as an `if` block.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
buffer = str(expadd(1000, 1000)
```

Your code is also indented incorrectly (the body of the `expadd` function should be indented), but due to the location of the error I assume that's only due to copy/pasting it here.